# AngularJS Odd Directive Scope Behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After describing my setup, my questions are below in bold.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <user-picker placeholder="Type a name..."></user-picker>
</div>
```

Setup:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.directives', 'app.controllers']);
var directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);
var ctrls = angular.module('app.controllers', []);
```

Controller:

```
ctrls.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'this is a foo';
});
```

Directive:

```
directives.directive('userPicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      placeholder: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'file.html',
    link: function postLink($scope, ele, attrs) {
      console.log($scope);
      console.log('[ng] Scope is: ');
      console.log($scope.placeholder);
      console.log($scope.$parent.foo);
  }
});
```

file.html (the directive):

```
<span>
  <input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" type="text">
</span>
```

So what I want to end up with, is generally working:

```
<span placeholder="Type a name...">
  <input placeholder="Type a name..." type="text">
</span>
```

The `placeholder` attribute is correctly resolved.

**Is this the right way to accomplish this?** Note that the attribute ends up in two places.

**Why this odd behavior:**
Secondly, I am baffled by the results of `console.log($scope)`. The console output reveals the accurately set `placeholder` attribtue on the `$scope` object. However, even still, the very next `console.log($scope.placeholder)` statement returns "undefined". How is this possible, when the console output clearly shows the attribute is set?

My goals are:

- Move or copy the `placeholder` attribute from the parent down to the child `<input>` tag.
- Have access to the template scope from within linking function.
- Reference the parent `MyCtrl` controller that this directive sits within.

I was almost there, until I ran into the odd behavior noted above. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You're doing it right as far as I can tell. The weirdness with the console has to do with the asynchronous stuff Angular is doing behind the scenes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571003/javascript-console-log-displays-different-values-on-same-object

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Do you know if there is a way to move attributes down to the children, rather than copying them (as I am ending up with above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attempting to read this off the scope would reading the attrs work?

Some HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="file.html">
    <span>
        <input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" type="text"/>
    </span>
</script>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <user-picker placeholder="Type a name..."></user-picker>
</div>
</body>
```

Some JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.directives', 'app.controllers']);
var directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);
var ctrls = angular.module('app.controllers', []);

ctrls.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'this is a foo';
});

directives.directive('userPicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            placeholder: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'file.html',
        link: function postLink($scope, ele, attrs) {
            console.log($scope);
            console.log('[ng] Scope is: ');
            console.log(attrs["placeholder"]);
            console.log($scope.$parent.foo);
        }
    }
});
```

A Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Rfks8/

Comment: You're right, that does work. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Anyways, thank you! :)